# WordPress meta_query syntax issue

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

Can anyone work out why the following syntax does work:

```
$results_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'meta_value' => '20161227',
    'posts_per_page' => 30
);
$results = new WP_Query($results_args);
```

but the following syntax does not?

```
$results_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'start_date',
            'value'   => '20161227',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);
$results = new WP_Query($results_args);
```

The latter code returns all posts where `post_type = 'event'`.

Docs are at https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters.

I'm looking to add multiple meta queries in, so I need the latter syntax to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Jamie

Comment: try adding 'meta_key' to you second array, even if you don't use it. E.g.: `'meta_key' => 'start_date', 'meta_query' => [ /* your array*/ ]`. Remember having a similar problem some time ago, but I don't have an WP installation handy...

Comment: Tried that, no luck. I think it may be a server issue, as `$results_args` changes as I would expect, but `$results->request` displays a very old query. Each time I use the former syntax, `$results->request` changes, then when I change again to the latter syntax, it reverts to that same old query. Any ideas?

Comment: No clue. I think it should work as it is. Sorry. :(

Comment: Will edit question as SQL produced is too long to comment

Comment: Just looked at the SQL code, and realised it's my own fault. I was using a `pre_get_posts` function to exclude historic events which was overwriting `meta_query` wherever `is_post_archive('event')` was `true`. I've restricted that code from operating where I'm using the query above. Thank you for making me explore the SQL code though, yivi. All works fine now.